# How to set edge\points margins with aChartEngine library

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm trying to use aChartEngine library, at the moment I'm doing some tests with the demo sample but I haven't found a way to set the margin between the edge points and their values.

See the screenshots

[image]

The code:

```
String[] titles = new String[] { "2008", "2007" };
    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    values.add(new double[] { 14230, 12300, 14240, 15244, 15900, 19200, 22030, 21200, 19500, 15500,
        12600, 14000 });
    values.add(new double[] { 5230, 7300, 9240, 10540, 7900, 9200, 12030, 11200, 9500, 10500,
        11600, 13500 });
    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN };
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
    setChartSettings(renderer, "Monthly sales in the last 2 years", "Month", "Units sold", 0.5,
        12.5, 0, 24000, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
    ((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0)).setDisplayChartValues(true);
    ((XYSeriesRenderer) renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1)).setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setXLabels(12);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
    // renderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
    renderer.setZoomRate(1.1f);
    renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5f);
    return ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,
        Type.STACKED);
```

How to set the margins to avoid the bars overlap the values at their ends?

Comment: Please note that this horizontal bar chart is only an experimental one.

Comment: @Dan
It's a very useful chart for comparison it's a pity that has bug like this. I really like achartengine library and hope these issues will be fixed asap. PS I have seen that singe 15th october no more night buld have been released.. what happens?

Comment: Cloudbees has probably blocked the AChartEngine account due to some changes in their pricing policies.

Comment: Is there any other ste where I could stay updated with latest 1.2 builds?

Comment: No, there isn't as far as I can tell.